# image switch with pure javascript

Tags: javascript, html, mouseout

so i'm trying to do a mouseover with just javascript so that the image doesn't really show up for seo i set it up in html first to get the css right and am making everything appear with document.write so it can be generated with javascript (my js knowledge is way limited). so with html i am making things with

```
<img src="img/brokenarrowwear-googleplus.png" onmouseover="this.src='img/brokenarrowwear-google-circle.png';" onmouseout="this.src='img/brokenarrowwear-googleplus.png';"/>
```

but since it uses "" and '' it doesn't really work. I tried doing it as

```
document.write(' <img src="img/brokenarrowwear-googleplus.png" onmouseover="this.src=' + 'img/brokenarrowwear-google-circle.png' + ';" onmouseout="this.src=' + 'img/brokenarrowwear-googleplus.png' + ';"/> ')
```

but that didn't really work either. does anyone know how i can do pure javascript? I found

```
$("img.image-1").mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).replaceWith($('<img src="~/Content/images/prosecutor_tile_b.jpg">'));
});
```

but I don't think it will work.

Comment: What do you mean by 'that the image doesn't really show up for seo'?

Comment: Why doesn't the first method (inline `onmouseover`) work? (works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/tfmzzea7/)

Comment: use \' instead of ' + '

Comment: re SEO: google does also read javascript code, and apparently they can now handle ajax too. They deprecated their recommendation for ajax content: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/learn-more#what-the-user-sees-what-the-crawler-sees

Comment: seo doesn't count the links as links so instead of having 50 links on a page i put half of them in javascript and it only counts 30 links now

Comment: @Felicyia - it's pretty reasonable for you to assume that whatever you can see and act on in the browser, google can also.

Comment: I run it through seo toolset and it shows that they aren't read as links

Comment: @Felicyia - seo toolset is not google. Don't ever think that you can write code to fool google's bot into thinking that your website is/does something differently than a live person actually experiences.

Comment: ah but when the boss thinks it does you do not argue

Comment: Use the first version, it should work if the src url is correct. Test with an absolute src path. @FelippeDuarte: can you give me a working example of that?

Comment: @yezzz - ok lots of postings not sure which part your tallking about

Comment: @Felicyia thanks for the seo info. Does it treat the inline link as canonical or something. Can you give me a good source for this, as I 've been out of seo for a while

Comment: @Felicyia Use your own first version... that should work, but test the urls. Your browser console may provide clues about loading errors.

Comment: my first version doesn't work that's why i posted it here lolz

Comment: also i don't have an article sorry. so i'm not really sure how it reads it but here's the test page for what i'm doing with this code http://www.embroiderywear.com/footertest.html

Comment: the code looks correct, that's why I said to check the urls... or it is a conflict with another script. Which browser did you test it in?

Comment: "this.src=' + \'img/ ...

Comment: so i did it like this document.write('      <img src="img/brokenarrowwear-facebook.png" onmouseover="this.src=' + \'img/brokenarrowwear-facebook-like.png'/ + ';" onmouseout="this.src=' + \'img/brokenarrowwear-facebook.png'/ + ';"/>') and it did not work. the whole thing just dissapeared http://www.embroiderywear.com/footertest.html

Comment: it's not the script, it's a rendering issue or a script conflict. See my answer

Answer (score 0):

Simple inline pure Javascript solution:

```
<script>
           document.write("<img src=\"http://placehold.it/150x150?text=image1\"   onmouseover=\"this.src='http://placehold.it/150x150?text=image2'\"  onmouseout=\"this.src='http://placehold.it/150x150?text=image1'\" />");     
</script>
```

The text says "image1" and on mouseover the text in the image will say "image2"

Comment: but that still has " " and ' ' so that won't work it has to fit between document.write(' ')

Comment: @Felicyia - just escape the `'` using `\'`. On a related note - what in the world are you doing using `document.write` for anything?

Comment: because that's the only way i knew how to "write" the content i needed to show up on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help:

```
<img id="mypic" src="img/brokenarrowwear-googleplus.png"  onmouseover='pictureChange(true)' onmouseout='pictureChange(false)'>
```

The function pictureChange:

```
function pictureChange(change){
    If(change==true){
        document.getElementById("mypic").src="img/brokenarrowwear-googleplus.png";
    }else{
    document.getElementById("mypic").src="img/brokenarrowwear-google-circle.png";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the script. I see it in the script source, but I'm not seeing it in the rendered html, actually the whole img tag is missing. Meaning You have some type of rendering issue or another script removed it.

Let's see if it's related to the inline javascript and escaping with backslashes doesn't work: remove the onmouseover and onmouseout attributes from the google img, give it an id="googlelogo" and add the following script at the end of your body:

```
<script>
document.getElementById("googlelogo").onmouseover = function() {
    this.src = "img/brokenarrowwear-google-circle.png";
  }
document.getElementById("googlelogo") .onmouseout = function() {
    this.src = "img/brokenarrowwear-googleplus.png";
  }
</script>
```